# Как получить значение из QListView?

Tags: python, qt, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

Есть список слов выводящийся через `QListView`.

Дальше нужно узнать выделеное слово и передать его в слот. Как это сделать?

Пробовал узнать через индекс или методы `QListWidget` от которого `QListView` унаследован, но ничего не получилось.

```
list.clicked.connect(lambda: self.changeStatus(???))
```

Comment: Наоборот, это QListWidget унаследован от QListView. У QListWidget есть сигнал itemClicked, который возвращает кликнутую элемент, а у того уже не сложно получить текст

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения данных из `QListView` нужно будет получить индекс значения и вытащить по индексу из модели их (этот код будет работать и для `QListWidget`, т.к. код имеет высокую абстракцию)

```
def item_clicked(index):
    if not index.isValid():
        return

    # Тут используется обращение к глобальной переменной, но можно передавать ссылку 
    # на список в функцию или работая в классе – к полю
    # По умолчанию, data возвращает значение Qt.DisplayRole – то, что отображается у 
    # элемента. Есть разные роли, например цвет текста, иконка
    value = list.model().data(index)

    print(value)

list.clicked.connect(item_clicked)
```

Если работать с `QListWidget`, то будет проще – `QListWidget` наследуется от `QListView` и уже имеет внутри себя модель:

```
def item_clicked(item):
    print(item.text())

list.itemClicked.connect(item_clicked)
```

Comment: @ferz, у меня не было возможности проверить код, поэтому пишите если он вызвал ошибку (их, вроде бы, не должно быть)

Comment: list.clicked.connect(lambda: self.changeStatus(list.model().data(list.currentIndex())))

Comment: вот так все норм